# Ng-options with subobject

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my array:

```
$scope.subscriptions = [
      {
        currency: {
          title: 'Euro',
          symbol: '€'
        },
        licenses: [
          {
            nrOfLicenses: 5,
            price: 500
          },
          {
            nrOfLicenses: 10,
            price: 750
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      currency: {
        title: 'SEK',
        symbol: 'kr'
      },
      licenses: [
        {
           nrOfLicenses: 5,
            price: 5000
         },
         {
            nrOfLicenses: 10,
            price: 7500
          }
      ]
    },    
  ]

  $scope.selectedSubscription = $scope.subscriptions[0];
```

I want a select box where you can choose currency.

I tried this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedSubscription.currency" ng-options="currency.title for currency in subscriptions"></select>
```

It's not working. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10066/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found your problem is was about you selector. You to browse all your subscription and take the title from the object currency in a subscription item. But you iterate over subscription object this the right code

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedSubscription" ng-options="subscription.currency.title for subscription in subscriptions"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedSubscription | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to change in the select like this :-

```
<select ng-model="selectedSubscription.currency" ng-options="sub.currency.title for sub in subscriptions"></select>
```

Here is updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gbsLa4wh/

Answer (score 0):

It might help you!!

Your HTML code-sample

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedSubscription.currency" ng-options="CuSub.currency.title for CuSub in subscriptions"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedSubscription.currency | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Your AngularJs code-sample

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.subscriptions = [
      {
        currency: {
          title: 'Euro',
          symbol: '€'
        },
        licenses: [
          {
            nrOfLicenses: 5,
            price: 500
          },
          {
            nrOfLicenses: 10,
            price: 750
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      currency: {
        title: 'SEK',
        symbol: 'kr'
      },
      licenses: [
        {
           nrOfLicenses: 5,
            price: 5000
         },
         {
            nrOfLicenses: 10,
            price: 7500
          }
      ]
    },    
  ]        
  $scope.selectedSubscription = $scope.subscriptions[0];
});
```